# How would I change this nested loop?

Tags: java, nested-loops

My short homework assignment tonight for my AP Computer Science class was to change this nested loop so that it printed 1, 3, 5, 7 stars instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 stars.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //print 1,3,5,7 stars
        for(int i=1; i<=7; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which number controls the number of stars printed? `i` or `j`?

Comment: Hint: `continue` statement.

Comment: Any thoughts, any ideas? You'll learn a lot more if you figure it out yourself. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase `i` by two not one

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i = i + 2)
```

or as suggested by @andreas

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i+= 2)
```

**output**

```
*
***
*****
*******
```

**edit**

As per a comment below by @andreas, in java11+ the following is also possible

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i += 2)
    System.out.println("*".repeat(i));
```

Comment: `i += 2` would be better, and is somewhat more consistent with `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

As [@ScaryWombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423847/2970947), you can increment `i` by two to achieve the desired pattern. I would prefer to eliminate the nested structure of the loop; you know the longest output is seven stars, initialize a constant `String` and print the appropriate substring of that for each line. Like,

```
String stars = "*******";
for (int i = 1; i <= stars.length(); i += 2) {
    System.out.println(stars.substring(0, i));
}
```

Comment: In Java 11+: `System.out.println("*".repeat(i));`

Comment: @Andreas That's nice